# Trying to update an existing textbox, but getting an "Object Required" error

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro, to get started with updating a Textbox.  Unfortunatley, as you know, recording a macro does not set the variables.

The recorded macro shows:

```
ActiveSheet.shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 8")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
  "Kroger Market 6 " & Chr(13) & "W/E P8 Week 4" & Chr(13) & "9/23/2020"
```

I tried to adjust this to:

```
With wsWeeklyDivision
    Dim EndDate As String
    EndDate = Left(Right(.Range("A4"), 24), 23)
End With

With wsFront
    Dim shapes As Variant
    shapes = shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 8"))
    With shapes
        .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Kroger Market 6 " & Chr(13) & "Date Range" & Chr(13) & Format(Now(), "MM.DD.YY")
    End With
End With
```

I even changed the `shapes = shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 8"))` to `Set shapes = shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 8"))`, but I'm still getting an Object Required error.

What do I need to change please?

Comment: `Set shapes = activesheet.shapes("TextBox 8")` ? And `dim shapes as shape`.

Comment: Having a variable called ```shapes``` might cause issues since ```shapes``` is already a built-in collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Set` when making Object assignments.

Shapes was never qualified.

> shapes = shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 8"))

`shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 8"))` returns a ShapeRange

```
With wsFront
    Dim ShapeRange As ShapeRange
    Set ShapeRange = .Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 8"))
    
    Dim TextBox8 As Shape
    Set TextBox8 = ShapeRange.Item(1)
    
    With TextBox8.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
        .Text = "Kroger Market 6 " & Chr(13) & "Date Range" & Chr(13) & Format(Now(), "MM.DD.YY")
    End With
End With
```

You only need to use a ShapeRange when the Shape is grouped.

```
With wsFront
    Dim TextBox8 As Shape
    Set TextBox8 = .Shapes("TextBox 8")
    
    With TextBox8.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
        .Text = "Kroger Market 6 " & Chr(13) & "Date Range" & Chr(13) & Format(Now(), "MM.DD.YY")
    End With
End With
```

Declaring your variables with the correct types makes it easier to code.  You can use TypeName to return an Objects type.

[image]

Make sure to match the capitalization when using a ClassName or standard property name.  T

Dim Shapes As Variant

Comment: You miss a `Set` in your 2nd example when assigning `TextBox8`. Beside this, good answer pointing out the difference between a `Shape` and a `ShapeRange`

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks!

Comment: @TinMan Thank you! I did try to use `Set`, but you're right, I was declaring `Shapes` as a `Shape` and not `ShapeRange`.    Thank you for the tip in regards to using the `TypeName` to return the object type.  I'll definitely be using this in the future!   However, how did you know to use `Item(1)` to get shape?  I guess I'm confused on how I would determine if the Shape is grouped, especially since the recorded macro stated `TextBox 8` was an array..?

Comment: @CDay Years of blood and sweat.  `.Range()` indicates that it is going to return a Range of values which will most likely be a collection of values.  Passing the `Array()` into the `Shapes.Range()` object suggests that you will get a collection of those named shapes back.  Item is also a standard method for any collection.  Similarly, `Worksheets(Array())` will return a collection of `Worksheets`.

Comment: @CDay You can also refer to a specific shape in a ShapeRange collection by it's name. Fo example:`wsFront.Shapes.Range(Array("Textbox 8", "Textbox 9")).Item("Textbox 8")`